# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'output' -- in a comment stripper program

Tags: python

So my program's basic intention is to take comments out of C files and display them.

```
import urllib2
import html2text
import re
import subprocess
from cStringIO import StringIO

url = raw_input('Please input URL youd like to analyze: ')
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html_content = page.read().decode('utf8')
rendered_content =
html2text.html2text(html_content).encode('ascii','ignore')

f = open('file_text.txt', 'wb')
f.write(rendered_content)
f.close()

fd = open("file_text.txt", "r")
buf = fd.read()

def comment_remover(text):
    def replacer(match):
        s = match.group(0)
            if s.startswith('/'):
                return " "
            else:
                return s

    pattern = re.compile(
        #Stackoverflow- properly removes all comments
        r'//.*?$|/\*.*?\*/|\'(?:\\.|[^\\\'])*\'|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"',
        re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE
    )
    return re.sub(pattern, replacer, text)

    input = StringIO(comment_remover(buf)) # source_code is a string with the source code.
    output = StringIO()

    process = subprocess.Popen(['sed', '/path/to/remccoms3.sed'], input=input, output=output)
    return_code = process.wait()

    stripped_code = output.getvalue()
```

Here's where I get the error message:

```
from linecache import getline

with open("file_text.txt") as f:
    for ind, line in enumerate(f,1):
        if line.rstrip() == "---|---":
            print(getline(f.name, ind + 4))
```

Basically the `line.rstrip == '---|---'` is the point in which, when I run the program, that line is where the comments from the actual page itself is showed, and not the comments from the source.

Comment: The only time you pass a keyword argument `output` to any `__init__` is when you call `subprocess.Popen`, and the correct keyword argument is `stdout`, not `output`.

Comment: While @chepner was able to figure out your error, please make sure you post the full traceback you are getting verbatim, next time. It will make it easier for people to help you.